# Use torch.square() inside a nn.Sequential layer in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I want to square the result of a maxpool layer.
I tried the following:

```
class CNNClassifier(Classifier):  # nn.Module
    def __init__(self, in_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters('in_channels')
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
            # maxpool
            nn.MaxPool2d((1, 5), stride=(1, 5)),
            torch.square(),
            # layer1
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, 
        )
```

Which to the experienced PyTorch user for sure makes no sense.

Indeed, the error is quite clear:

> TypeError: square() missing 1 required positional arguments: "input"

How can I feed in to square the tensor from the preceding layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a PyTorch function in a [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html) pipeline, it needs to be a [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=nn%20module#torch.nn.Module).

You could wrap it like this:

```
class Square(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.square(x)
```

Then use it inside your sequential layer like so:

```
class CNNClassifier(Classifier):  # nn.Module
    def __init__(self, in_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters('in_channels')
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool2d((1, 5), stride=(1, 5)),
            Square(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5))
```